# Python: How to write to CSV and append date from a DataFrame to the filename

Tags: python, date, csv, filenames

I am using the following method to write to a csv file with the date appended to the filename.

```
outpath = r'C:\test'
filename = "filename_"+(time.strftime("%Y%m%d")+".csv")

df.to_csv(outpath + "\\" + filename)


print outpath + "\\" + filename

C:\test\filename_20140621.csv
```

But I have a problem when the routine crosses midnight and the date added is then incorrect.

I have the correct date in a DataFrame df, like this:

```
df['Date/Time'].head()
Out[54]:

0   2014-06-20
1   2014-06-20
2   2014-06-20
3   2014-06-20
4   2014-06-20
Name: Date/Time, dtype: object
```

I would like to use this date in the filename, but I can't find the correct way to reference it

For example, I put this date in a new dataframe named 'date' with just the one column:

```
date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'])
date.head()

Out[15]:

0   2014-06-20
1   2014-06-20
2   2014-06-20
3   2014-06-20
4   2014-06-20
Name: Date/Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

and tried the following:

filename = "filename_"+ date._slice(slice(1))+".csv")

...and various similar things.

Can anybody show me how to set the filename to include the date from the DataFrame?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your `date` Series, you could take the first, or the least, as you prefer:

```
>>> date.head()
0   2014-06-20
1   2014-06-20
2   2014-06-20
3   2014-06-20
4   2014-06-20
Name: Date/Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> date.iloc[0].strftime("%Y%m%d")
'20140620'
>>> date.min().strftime("%Y%m%d")
'20140620'
```

`.iloc[0]` accesses the first row (regardless of whether its index is 0, as it is here, or 217123), and `.min()` scans them all and finds the smallest.  (If you know they're all the same, or that the one you want will be first, then `.iloc[0]` will be faster than `.min()`, of course, but maybe they're not sorted and you want the smallest.. or the largest, with `max()`.)

Then you can make a filename easily:

```
>>> datestr = date.min().strftime("%Y%m%d")
>>> 'filename_{}.csv'.format(datestr)
'filename_20140620.csv'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the datetime module. Is this what you expect?

```
import datetime
def _getToday():
        return datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
outpath = r'C:\test'
filename = "%s_%s.%s" % ("filename", _getToday() ,".csv")

print outpath + "\\" + filename
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, Bala, but it wasn't today's date I needed to reference, it was a date from a DataFrame/Series

Answer (score 1):

When using this with `pd.ExcelWriter`–this worked:

```
datestr = tdy.strftime("%Y%m%d")

x = 'FileName_{}.xlsx'.format(datestr)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(x, engine= "xlsxwriter")
```